# Static Files Django - HEROKU

Tags: django, heroku, heroku-postgres

When I turn off the PC and turn it back on and try to edit a static file on django this doesn't work.  To make it work I have to rename it, and since I use HEROKU to host my site I don't want to use this method.  Is there an alternative for not renaming static files and making them work anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What "does not Work"? Please provide a bit more information.

I guess the changes you made in the static file are not shown in your browser? For that you should delete your browser cache for this site.

for Chrome try:
`your site, then click Inspect < Network Tab < disable cache < refresh your site`

its ok for testing and dev. For further deployment you should look into [Django Doc Static Files Hash](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#manifeststaticfilesstorage). You should provide your static files with a hash value, if you collect your static files. So your browser and the browsers of your users will know to update the cache automatically like `my_style.55e7cbb9ba48.css`.